# Why is my analytics tracking code using AWS SDK no longer working?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

Using PHP, I was loading a script in the footer of my site for analytics tracking purposes. This code, until recently, was working. And then one day I noticed the following error in my console:

`GET http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Steps I've taken:

1. Tried updating the JS version for the SDK (I was loading v2.1.35, whereas the current version is v.2.2.32). But that approach was a dead-end road.
2. Given the details of the console error, I thought the issue might involve the GET request using http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php, as this is a page that no longer appears to exist. But again, no luck.

Is there a culprit in my script I'm not accounting for?

`<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.1.35.min.js"</script>`

```
  AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: '[redacted for security]', secretAccessKey: '[redacted for security]'});
  var QUEUE_URL = 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/[redacted for security]';
  var sqs = new AWS.SQS({region : 'us-east-1'});
  var d = new Date();
  var ip = "::1";
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xmlhttp.open("GET","http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php",true);
  xmlhttp.onload = function e() {
    response = xmlhttp.responseText;
    hostipInfo = response.split("\n");
    for (i=0; hostipInfo.length > i; i++) {
      ipAddress = hostipInfo[i].split(":");
      if ( ipAddress[0] == "IP" ) {
        ip = (ipAddress[1]).trim();
        var clf = ip + ' - - [' + d.getTime() + '] "GET ' + window.location.pathname + ' HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "' + navigator.userAgent + '" ' + window.location.hostname;
        var params = {
          MessageBody: clf,
          QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL
        };
        sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err,data){
          if(err) console.log('error:',"Fail Send Message" + err);
          else    console.log('such wow');
        });
        console.log(clf);
      }
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.timeout = 3000;
  xmlhttp.ontimeout = function () {
    var ip  = "::1";
    var clf = ip + ' - - [' + d.getTime() + '] "GET ' + window.location.pathname + ' HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "' + navigator.userAgent + '"';
    var params = {
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify(clf),
      QueueUrl: QUEUE_URL
    };
    sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err,data){
      if(err) console.log('error:',"Fail Send Message" + err);
      else    console.log('such wow');
    });
    console.log(clf);
  }
  xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php` is down. Open the page in your browser and you will see it's not working.